# SQL Server - Assignment (sum) of the volume of the last 52 weeks to a given week

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when, partition-by

> I am trying to use partition-by in SQL to evaluate a complex value

It is the sum of volume from the last 56 to 4 weeks window to a given week in data.

Table's attributes: Product, Shop, Week, Category, Volume

**Data**: More than 150 weeks of data,

**Goal**: select value for 'CategoryWeekVolume', which is the the sum of volume from the last 56-4 weeks for a given category.

**Tried**: I've tried case-whens, over-partition-by in a multiple combinations, but I'm not that experienced when it comes to SQL, and 
I have no idea how to do it in a smart way, without adding 52 columns with volume from a week-4 upto week-56.

The general condition is 
`t0.[WEEK]-t1.[WEEK]>4 and t0.[WEEK]-t1.[WEEK]<57`  and 
the sum should be per category.

I'd really appreciate any inputs.

Comment: Sample data, expected results (as formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements) and your attempts (the actual SQL you wrote) will really help here.

Comment: `sum(case when t0.[WEEK]-t1.[WEEK] > 4 and t0.[WEEK]-t1.[WEEK] < 57 then volume else null end) over(partition by category)`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Week` is `INT`:

```
SELECT 
  Category,
  Week, 
  SUM(Volume) AS CategoryWeekVolume 
FROM 
  tablename
WHERE 
  Week 
  BETWEEN 
    (SELECT MAX(Week) FROM tablename) - 56 
    AND
    (SELECT MAX(Week) FROM tablename) - 4 
GROUP BY Category, Week
```